# Custom CPU fan control profile in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I have a Gigabyte motherboard which I can use EasyTune6 on. Afaik. it allows you to set the CPU fan control profile, so I can set how much voltage the fan gets by certain CPU temperatures. To my experience this feature ends when I uninstall EasyTune6 and everything returns to default. Is there a way to set things like this without running every time a program at startup?

Afaik. it is possible with some registry tweaks, but I don't know the details. Currently the "smart" fan control lets my CPU overheat, it keeps the fan on 400 RPM, while the CPU temperature is over 60°C by some of the cores. I'd like to have 1400 RPM at these temperatures. Disabling smart fan control and keep the fan on 1400 RPM constantly is too noisy for me.

I installed EasyTune6 again to check how it works.

[image]

The fan speed (RPM) appears to depend on something called "temperature #2" instead of the core temperatures of the CPU. I highly doubt that this is normal behavior. :S

Apparently the motherboard and EasyTune6 thinks that the CPU temperature is much lower than it really is.

[image]

I am pretty sure the fan is on the good header. I took a photo of it.

[image]

Amd here is the relevant section from the motherboard manual:

[image]

I shorted the manual control of the CPU fan with a jumper to achieve the max fan speed.

Afaik. pin 4 is for PWM, which this fan does not support.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like something isn't working properly? Do you have any BIOS options available in this regard? Usually you will need to run some additional software to actively influence it if it isn't properly managed by the system/BIOS.

Comment: @Seth Yes, I can select smart fan enabled, disabled or auto. Disabled means max speed enabled means that I can change the settings with easytune. What is interesting, that it does not seem to react on the core temperatures properly. When I set it to have 10% speed by 20°C and 100% by 40°C, I got about 33% speed by 55°C cores.

Comment: @Seth I updated my question, maybe it helps to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure you connected the Fan to the right header on the motherboard?

Comment: @Seth Yes, I am sure. The header has CPU FAN label. Should I take a photo?

Comment: @Seth I found the same value in EasyTune6, it thinks that the `temperature #2` is the CPU temperature. Any ideas?

Comment: @Seth I updated the question with more info.

Comment: Hmm probably the problem is caused a bad sensor or bad thermal paste appliance. I'll apply a new thermal paste on it, I just ordered it. Maybe that solves the problem. Until then I'll use the manual fan control or disable the smart control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is supported by UEFI only, and mine is an UEFI-BIOS hybrid. So I am not able to do this on the motherboard.

In Windows I did not check, but it does not matter, because I just realized, that Speccy, EasyTune, HwInfo and most of the sensor reader applications show wrong sensor data and the real temperature is 20°C lower. This is because I have a 771 Xeon in a 775 board. Only Aida64 shows the proper temperatures. I ended up using a manual fan control, but it is usually set to max, since I used to the noise.